# Oracle Forms: How to get rid of security warning(s) related to JAR signing?

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms

We are upgrading to Oracle Forms 11gR2. After the upgrade when I open my application in Development its giving me the security warning:

> "Do you want to Run this application". Publisher : Unknown.

I explored and found we have to get a signed Certificate from CA (which I believe will cost money). I tried a self-signed certificate but still it's showing the warning message. Can anybody share the steps to get and import self-signed certificate for my Application?

I know only the Development URL and having admin rights. I don't have any source code for JAR.

Comment: I suggest googling a bit for that same question.  Your question has probably already been answered, but, as it is, it's not written very clearly, there is not enough information to go on.  Have you tried anything and, if so, what?  Please include more information and your findings so others have an idea of how to help you.

Comment: We are upgrading to Oracle Forms 11gR2  . After upgrading when im opening my application ( Development ) its giving me the security warning.  "Do you want to Run this application" . Publisher : Unknown . I explored and found we have to get the Signed Certificate from CA ( i believe this include cost )  . Kindly suggest any other method to get rid of this warning .

Comment: You can use a self-signed certificate.

Comment: i used self -signed certificate . But still its showing the warring message .

Comment: Kindly share the steps for get and import self-signed certificate for my Application . ( I know only the Development URL and having admin rights ) . I dont have any source code , JAR  .

Comment: I suggest you ask your question of the Oracle Technet forum for Forms. You're way more likely to find experts in the tool there than on a general programming site. [Find it here](https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/forms/content) I suggest you use my version of your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Java checks from a certain version (I think 1.7 u21) if everything it needs to run that is not local is secure. This mean it needs a valid certificate and not a self signed version.

If however you still want to run your java applet without the signing or a self signed version you can make exceptions in the java control panel in the security tab, there you've got a button edit site list...
If you add here the url you start fe: http://localhost:8888/forms/frmservlet?config=webutil then you can start the forms. You still need to say everything is ok to run it and not block it. But it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using self-signed certificate, then you can import the certificate to java and that would solve the issue.
another way is to change the java.policy file.